# Meteor build fails on Windows 10 - Process out of memory

Tags: node.js, windows, memory, meteor

Up until now I have only used my imac and my macbook to work on my app and had very few issues. I now want to be able to use my Windows pc as well but after 2 days of messing around, I just can't get my app to run. I can create a new app and it runs fine.

I have installed Meteor with [Chocolatey](https://www.meteor.com/install) as instructed, with no issues.

I then pulled my app from the git repo, ran `npm install`, and then `meteor run`. All goes well until the 'Linking' phase where it shows up with this error...

```
    C:\Users\Me\Desktop\myapp>meteor --settings settings-development.json                                             
    [[[[[ C:\Users\Me\Desktop\myapp]]]]]

    => Started proxy.
    => A patch (Meteor 1.5.4.2) for your current release is available!
       Update this project now with 'meteor update --patch'.
       Linking                                   -
    <--- Last few GCs --->

       58416 ms: Mark-sweep 678.5 (734.8) -> 678.5 (734.8) MB, 309.8 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [scavenge might not succeed].
       58824 ms: Mark-sweep 678.5 (734.8) -> 689.2 (734.8) MB, 407.8 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [scavenge might not succeed].
       59177 ms: Mark-sweep 689.2 (734.8) -> 689.0 (734.8) MB, 353.2 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
       59528 ms: Mark-sweep 689.0 (734.8) -> 689.2 (734.8) MB, 351.0 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


    <--- JS stacktrace --->

    ==== JS stack trace =========================================

    Security context: 37E25599 <JS Object>
        1: JSONSerialize(aka JSONSerialize) [native json.js:~120] [pc=0DA21153] (this=37E08099 <undefined>,G=37E6D451 <String[4]: data>,j=09243DF1 <an Object with map 2D019699>,v=09243E49 <JS Function replacer (SharedFunctionInfo 2350ECD1)>,w=09243EC9 <JS Array[2]>,x=37E08365 <String[0]: >,y=37E08365 <String[0]: >)
        2: SerializeObject(aka SerializeObject) [native json.js:97] [pc=0DA23534] (this=37E080...

    FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory

    C:\Users\Me\Desktop\myapp>
```

Obviously it is related to running out of memory. What I have gathered from many articles/threads etc. is that I need to set the `TOOL_NODE_FLAGS="--max-old-space-size=4096"`.

For some reason though, after I run `set TOOL_NODE_FLAGS="--max-old-space-size=4096"`, I am no longer able to run 'meteor run'. the command prompt thinks for a second, and then nothing happens...

So if I run `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\myapp>meteor --settings settings-development.json`, I get the error above.

If I run `C:\Users\Serks\Desktop\cakenote>set TOOL_NODE_FLAGS="--max-old-space-size=4096"` and then run `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\myapp>meteor --settings settings-development.json`, nothing happens and the cursor returns to...`C:\Users\Serks\Desktop\cakenote`.

Does anyone know how I can get meteor to start with more memory on Windows 10 through cmd line?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think this option worked in meteor 1.5

Please see this thread
https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-wont-start-with-max-old-space-size-solved/44745

Comment: Correct. After upgrading Meteor, I was able to use `set TOOL_NODE_FLAGS="--max-old-space-size=4096"`.